# Login with Google+ Account using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I Have one Desktop application in swing and now i want to allow user to login with Google+ account so how could i do that any idea? I Want to allow user to Login in my application with Google+ account any suggestion?

Comment: I have dome so many things but going out of mind. can u give me sample code link.

Comment: The first thing to read should be https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp